# Which suggestion is best for adjusting layout to users viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

my goal is to achieve a nice design crossover smartphone, tablet and desktop. There is no need of suit perfectly! The website is highly dynamic - like an answer-question game. After each answer a new question (complex structure of div and li elements) is generated

1. Send request through ajax to php and get back the complete html; correct width and height of all elements afterwards with jquery
2. Send request through  ajax and receive just the core information in json format; build the html completely in jquery
3. Use the best matching stylesheet according to the viewport; Send request through ajax and receive the complete html

In my opinion suggestion 3 offers adequate accuracy and would probably perform better than the others.

Suggestion 3 a bit more detailed would work like this (just an example!):

```
switch(viewport){
 case > 1200 => include stylesheet1
 case > 980 => include stylesheet2
 case > 600 => include stylesheet3
 case > 400 => include stylesheet4
 case <=400 => include stylesheet5
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) in Javascript?

Comment: Hi i heard aboud media queries, but im not sure whether the width is calculated correctly. Now i have the following:
Is mobile (yes => viewport = window.screen.availWidth; no => viewport = $(window).width())
So i need the availWidth on mobile device and not the scaled (mostly 980 px i guess).

Comment: You should rely on the `scaled` width, actually because that is what the user wants. Otherwise, you can disallow scaling with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this isn't technically an answer to your question, as I am making my own suggestion:

You should use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). That let's you define a style for every specific viewport you need to design for.

Comment: +1 for media queries, especially with a [mobile first approach](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)